# Why is this flow invisible?

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow that's not visible in Setup | Flows. Its existence was turned up via "Where is this used" on a field.  It can be opened via the link.

I tried saving this as a new flow and got the following error:

> "The value for ObjectVariable is 'null', which isn't a flow sObject
>   variable of objectType 'null' that allows input assignment."

I'm not seeing a variable named "ObjectVariable" in the flow anywhere.

Is there a way to restore this flow to visibility or will it need to be re-created from scratch?

Comment: Are you able to retrieve it in Developer Workbench or VS Code and view the metadata to see if there's anything unusual compared to other Flows?

Comment: I am facing the EXACT same issue. Are you able to find a solution for this? Any positive update is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We have the same symptoms. Salesforce Support said to look at Process Builder, and sure enough, the flow is a Process Builder flow! It appears in the PB list of flows. We can edit it there. It opens in the Process Builder editor, unlike the "where is this used" link, which opens it in the Flow Builder editor (and that won't work). We can deactivate the flow, and clone it, and save it, like normal, in the Process Builder.

Answer (score 1):

If you use HappySoup.io (free and community-led open source project) to see where a field is used, the results will tell you which flows are real flows vs which ones are process builders. This would've saved you a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this same question while attempting to fix a Flow. I arrived at the Flow Builder tool from the dependencies in Object Manager. As other answers alluded to, this should have been handled in Process Builder. I simply opened the same dependency in Process Builder and was able to resolve the issue.